# Php function returns always zero

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, function

I've a form with a password field

```
<form id="form-login" class="row-fluid" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="#">
<input class="span12" type="password" name="password" pattern="[0-9 ]{5,15}" />
</form>
```

when submit the form I do an Ajax call:

```
...
var data = $('form').serialize();

$.ajax({

    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // wordpress
    type: "POST",
    data: data + '&action=login_check',
    cache: false,

    success: function (html) {           
        $('.loading').hide();

        if ( html == 0 ) {
            $('.undone').fadeIn('slow');
        } else if ( html == 1 ) {
            $('.done').fadeIn('slow');                  
        }
    }
}); 

return false;
...
```

that check password using this function in `functions.php` (Wordpress):

```
function login_check(){

        $pw = 'hello';

        if( md5($pw) == md5($_POST['password']) ){

            $_SESSION['key'] = 1;
            return 1;

        } else {

            return 0;

        }

    die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_login_check', 'login_check');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_login_check', 'login_check');
```

and I want that the above function returns 0 or 1 to the `success` function in the ajax call. But it returns always `0`, also when insert the correct password. Where am i wrong?

```
var_dump($_POST);

array(3) {
  ["password"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  ["s"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["action"]=>
  string(11) "login_check"
}
```

Comment: what are you getting in `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: Try to put return statement in if clause as well. Current It's only for else clause. And then check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check for a `Number` in your javascript ajax callback handler. But the `html` param will be acutally a `String`. Change the callback to:

```
if ( html == '0' ) {
    $('.undone').fadeIn('slow');
} else if ( html == '1' ) {
    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');                  
}
```

What happens? You formally, (before edition the question) returned nothing `''` on success and `'0'` an error. But because of the loose typing system of javascript both evaluated to `==0`. Check this javascript code:

```
""==0;  // true
"0"==0; // true
```

---

Also change the `return` statements in PHP into `echo` statements. Note that the `return` statement actually outputs nothing:

```
if( md5($pw) == md5($_POST['password']) ){
    $_SESSION['key'] = 1;
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
```

Comment: What gives you `alert('>>' + html + '<<');` ? Any whitespace before or after the content?

Comment: it gives always the same damn zero: `>>0<<` (no whitespace)

Comment: YEAH, it works! this is called EXPERIENCE! thanks so much! :) but why `echo` and not `return`? :\

Comment: Simple, because `return` in PHP will return values to any PHP code which called the function, it will not return values to any JavaScript, and vice versa

Comment: You are welcome! Note that both problems together (javascript and php) lead to the situation that you *though* that it is always returning `0`